# onBeforeSaveUser vs onSaveUser

Tags: plugin-development, users

I'm trying to make a very basic plugin that will send an email alert to a User if an Admin changes their User Group.

I thought I could use the onBeforeSaveUser to get the User's current User Group, and then use the onSaveUser event to compare that with the Event's User Group - and then if they differ, do the mail sending.

It doesn't work, and I don't know why. Both events always get the same value for the User Group. What am I not understanding correctly?

```
private $existingGroups = NULL;

public function init()
{
    craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {
        $eventUser = $event->params['user']; // get the user we are editing

        $user = craft()->users->getUserById($eventUser->id); // get that user's existing information, before we edit it

        $this->existingGroups = $user->getGroups(); // store the groups the User belongs to
        GroupNotificationPlugin::log("existingGroup: " . $this->existingGroups[0]->name, LogLevel::Info);
    });

    craft()->on('users.onSaveUser', function(Event $event) {
        $user = $event->params['user']; // get the user we are editing

        GroupNotificationPlugin::log("Was: " . $this->existingGroups[0]->name, LogLevel::Info);
        GroupNotificationPlugin::log("Now: " . $user->getGroups()[0]->name, LogLevel::Info);

        if($this->existingGroups[0]->name != $user->getGroups()[0]->name){
            GroupNotificationPlugin::log("Changing group", LogLevel::Info);
        }
    });
}
```

Was: XXX and Now: XXX are always reporting the same, even when I know that I have changed the User Group (unchecking the old one, checking a new one, saving).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both [onSaveUser](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onSaveUser) and [onBeforeSaveUser](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onBeforeSaveUser) get fired from [UsersService->saveUser()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#saveUser-detail) and user group assignment happens in the [UsersController->actionSaveUser()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionSaveUser-detail) *after* `UsersService->saveUser()` has already been called.

You should probably be using [onBeforeAssignUserToGroups](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#userGroups-onBeforeAssignUserToGroups) and [onAssignUserToGroups](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#userGroups-onAssignUserToGroups) instead.